# Mesh distorted when armature bone rotates

Tags: animation, bones, transforms, weight-painting

My character's arm starts to get suck when rotated on x axis. I tried weight paint and it does not seem to help much I'm really new to Blender and 3D animation and any critique is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to weight paint only the arm and not the rest of the body. The problem may also be that the armature bone is too short. This will make the rig to be in imbalance and this kind of problem occur. Good luck! You can link the .blend file here is it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to retopologize and/or change the bone's influence with **distance** and **radius** params. Oh, and you seem to have too few bones to the limbs. By the way, limb rigging IS an uneasy thing an often gives undesired effects like the one you presented.  Hence, it's best to use the Riggify add-on that now comes with Blender.